# How to fetch second row from the CSV file using ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

The CSV file will be downloaded after clicking on the button present on the application and contains the same data as the table.
Scenario-: I have to test the whether the data in the csv file contains the same data as the table contains on the application.

Comment: Hi, please add the code of your tries or the error messages or describe where you have  problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily open the CSV and fetch the rows input. I assume you have a csv file like this:

```
id,attr1,attr2,attr3
1,dat1,dat1,dat1
2,dat2,dat2,dat2
```

In your application or test do

```
require 'csv'

csv_file_name = 'path_to_file.csv'

csv_file = File.open(csv_file_name, 'r')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_file, :headers => true)

csv.each do |row|
  row = row.to_hash.with_indifferent_access
  row_hash = row.to_hash.symbolize_keys

  // access to data in the row
  puts row_hash[:id]
  puts row_hash[:attr1]
  puts row_hash[:attr2]
  puts row_hash[:attr3]
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I only want to fetch the second row from the csv file and match it with second row of the table present on the application.

Comment: What are you aiming for ? Is this a test ? What is "second row of the table present on the application" ? Without showing code we cannot help you the right way

Comment: actual_row = File.open(file_name[0], 'r')


    first_row_data = []

    CSV.foreach(actual_row) do |row|
      first_row_data << row[1]
    end
   puts first_row_data
With this I am trying to fetch the second row of CSV but it is printing the second column instead.